# Selecionar parte de Texto no R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

Gostaria de filtrar elementos específicos de uma linha, semelhante ao filtro do Excel. Tenho o seguinte exemplo:

```
NOME    VALOR
LEITO 1 10
LEITO 2 - HPP   20
LEITO 3 - HPP   30
LEITO 4 40
```

Preciso filtrar, na coluna nome, a linhas com os caracteres `HPP`. O resultado final do filtro deve ficar assim:

```
NOME    VALOR
LEITO 2 - HPP   20
LEITO 3 - HPP   30
```

Como faço para fazer este filtro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os pacotes `dplyr` e `stringr` podem te ajudar nisso. Primeiro, vou criar o conjunto de dados:

```
NOME  <- c("LEITO 1", "LEITO 2 - HPP", "LEITO 3 - HPP", "LEITO 4")
VALOR <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
dados <- data.frame(NOME, VALOR)
```

A seguir, carrego os pacotes necessários:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
```

Por fim, uma combinação das funções `filter`, que seleciona linhas de acordo com algum critério, e `str_detect`, que procura por um trecho específico de caracteres dentro de um conjunto maior de caracteres:

```
dados %>% 
  filter(str_detect(NOME, "HPP"))
           NOME VALOR
1 LEITO 2 - HPP    20
2 LEITO 3 - HPP    30
```

Comment: como ficaria a função se eu filtrar mais de uma opção? Por exemplo, filtrar palavras que contêm  "HPP"  ou "HPP2".Grato.